# how to send integer number via sheared memory in linux

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to send integer data via  a shared memory in linux it works very well with string

```
const char *msg="hello";
```

but when I try this gives me error

```
const int *msg=25;
```

and when I try to print the contain of the address for string works

```
printf("%s",(char *) ptr);
```

but for this I have error

```
printf("%d",(int *)ptr);
```

and I try to write this but I give me the address not the contain of the address

```
printf("%d",*(int *)ptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code,

```
 const int *msg=25;
```

is likely to produce weird result, as, you're assigning a pointer address to get a value `25` which is most likely to be an *invalid* address in respect to your program. It's most likely you don't intend to do that.

Instead, write

```
const int msg=25;
```

and use `&msg` to get the address of that variable.

FWIW, the above changes (*note the plural form*) will solve the issue with `printf()`, too, and, the `cast`s are not required, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s",(char *) ptr);
```

The cast to `char *` is unneeded.

```
printf("%d",(int *)ptr);
```

In order to get the value the pointer is pointing to, use `*`. So you'd write:

```
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

Also dont assign raw addresses to pointers, because you (usually) dont know what is in that address. In your example, address `25` might be anything. Dereferencing that pointer will likely cause a segfault( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

So instead of that you should do this:

```
int a = 25;
int *addr = &a;  /* addr contains the address of a */
```

To print `addr`:

```
printf("%p", addr);
```

Or if `%p` is unavailable for your compiler, use `%u`.